# How do you show almost sure convergence to infinity?

Tags: probability-theory

I am having some trouble understanding the methods one uses to show almost sure convergence to $\infty$.

I mean, usually when proving a.s. convergence, I pretty much always use Borell-Cantelli which involves a hypothethical limit and the sum $\sum P(|X_n - X| \ge \epsilon)$. But how do I make sense of $\sum P(|X_n - \infty| \ge \epsilon)$?

In particular the question I am working on concerns $\sum_{k=1}^n (1/k) X_k$, where $X_k$ are iid variables with distribution $N(1, \sigma^2)$.  I need to show that this converges to infinity almost surely.

My confusion is increased by the fact that $V ((1/k)X_k) = \sigma^2/k^2$, and so the infinite sum of variances are converging to some finite value. But in that case, does the Khinchin-Kolmogorov theorem not guarantee convergence to some finite limit? Which would make the exercise contradictory?

Comment: Thanks for the -1. Very constructive criticism which definitely helped explain what's wrong with my question and has ensured that I won't repeat this mistake in the future. Thanks for making this site a more efficient and better place for math learners, you down-voting genius.

Comment: 1. If you want to use the Borel cantelli lemma to prove divergence you have to show that $\sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \leq k)< \infty$ for all $k \geq 1$. 2. Note that Kolmogorov's theorem entails $$\sum_k (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k))< \infty$$ almost surely; this does not imply $\sum_k X_k<\infty$ almost surely 3. Since $X_k \sim N(1,\sigma^2)$ we know that it is very likely that $X_k$ takes a value close to $1$. Since $\sum_k \frac{1}{k} = \infty$ there is no reason to expect that $\sum_k X_k/k$ converges.